# Confusing index out of bounds in shapes collection

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, ms-word, office-interop

I am attempting to fix an inconsistent problem in some VB NET code that uses the MS Office Interop libraries.  Running using the same files and data, the following code throws this exception:

> The index into the specified collection is out of bounds.
>   
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>   
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.EnumeratorViewOfEnumVariant.MoveNext()
>   
> at myProject.TableNotePages(clsUsrDoc& usrdoc) in path\file.vb:line 1454
>   
> ...

Line 1454 is the iShp += 1 line

```
Dim MyDoc As Word.Document = usrdoc.Document
Dim NoteBoxes As New Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary(Of Integer, Word.TextFrame)
Dim iShp As Integer = 1
For Each shp As Word.Shape In MyDoc.Sections.First.Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes
    If Not shp.TextFrame.Next Is Nothing Then
        NoteBoxes.Add(iShp, shp.TextFrame)
        iShp += 1
    End If
Next
```

There are a few questions that might help me solve this:

1. Why doesn't this happen every time?
2. Is the framework moveNext method in the trace called on the last non-conditional line of the loop instead of on the "for each" or "next" lines(adding another line between iShp += 1 and End If causes it to fail on that line instead)?
3. Is there something unusual about VB foreach loops (My expertise is more in C/Java) or interop collections that would cause it to attempt iterating beyond the end of the shapes collection?

Any insight to what might be occurring here is appreciated.

Comment: Can you change yoru ForEach to a For loop? I've had trouble with that in the past with interopt problems, can't remember why. But doing that would give me a different error that was more helpful.

Comment: `iShp += 1` really shouldn't be raising an exception. It must happen two lines later...

Comment: @the_lotus Yes, that was the next thing I tried.  Thus far, it seems okay.  I haven't seen enough to be convinced it is always okay though and the behavior is still alarming.

Comment: @djv I agree.  Adding another line after that changes the line to the added line so it's not off by some number of lines.  My best guess is the way VB NET / VS2013 compiles causes the iteration to occur immediately after the last non-structural (not on END IF) line and thus the exception is reported on that line.  Hopefully someone can confirm or refute that, although the more interesting question is why the exception is thrown at all.

Comment: Let us know if the For end up working. I know I ended up with the habit of never using ForEach for interup collections.

Comment: @codemonk are you compiling as Debug or Release?

Comment: @djv I am compiling as Release

Comment: @codemonk that's probably why the line is off. Does this issue happen when compiled as Debug?

Comment: Since you don't provide repro steps for the content the code is running on nor provide a [mcve], all anyone can do is guess. But: `Headers[Index].Shapes` will pick up *all* `Shape` objects in the document's Headers, not just that of the first section. If you specifically want only the one header use `Headers[Index].Range.ShapeRange` to get the `Shapes` collection (enumeration). In my experience, there's no problem working with these collections in loops...

Comment: @djv The line reported is the line with "NEXT" when running in debug.  It took 7 tries running on the same docs/data to see it fail.

Comment: @codemonk does it happen if you tack on `.ToList` at the end of the shapes collection i.e. `For Each shp As Word.Shape In MyDoc.Sections.First.Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes.ToList()` ?

Comment: The shapes collection does not seem to have or inherit the ToList method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.shapes?view=word-pia

Comment: Try the following for Line 1452:  `If Not shp?.TextFrame?.Next Is Nothing Then`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like once in a while vb/word interop arbitrarily walks off the end of the shapes collection.  The below code, replacing "for each" with "for x to y," has run successfully a statistically significant number of times (about 50) across a few environments.  I know this is not a good answer and still does not answer the question as to why this happens, but does solve the problem so posting as an answer in case an example helps someone else:

```
    Dim MyDoc As Word.Document = usrdoc.Document
    Dim NoteBoxes As New Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary(Of Integer, Word.TextFrame)
    Dim iShp As Integer = 1
    Dim loopLength As Integer = MyDoc.Sections.First.Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes.Count
    Dim shp As Word.Shape = Nothing
    For i As Integer = 1 To loopLength '1-indexed
        shp = MyDoc.Sections.First.Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes(i)
        If Not shp.TextFrame.Next Is Nothing Then
            NoteBoxes.Add(iShp, shp.TextFrame)
            iShp += 1
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: The Dim for shp should be moved into the scope of the For loop. Otherwise the previous value of shp will persist in the next iteration. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619430/vb-net-for-loop-function-scope-vs-block-scope/32620400#32620400

Comment: @вʀaᴎᴅᴏƞвєнᴎєƞ That value persisting is not a problem.  I'd just as so not incur the cost of initializing vs assignment on every iteration even if it is probably trivial in this case.  The MSDN link ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope ) in your SO link (why not link directly?) suggests it would be "wise" to initialize it every time and reads like a style suggestion to me.  It's pretty irrelevant to anything going on here.